# Properly embed JavaScript variables in Ruby on Rails 4.x

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using Ruby on Rails 4 and am trying to write a JavaScript that requires server-side data to populate. For instance, I might have a control called StudentsController and I want to return all particular students from a particular class. So in my controller I might do:

```
def index
  @students = Student.all
end
```

I then have a script in `/app/assets/javascripts/` called `foo.js` and in there I'm trying to split the students up by their `class_id`.

in `foo.js`

```
$(function() {
    var class_a = <%= @students.select { |s| s.class_id = 'a' }.to_json %>
    var class_b = <%= @students.select { |s| s.class_id = 'b' }.to_json %>
})
```

Problem is `class_a` is null when I'm checking on the browser side of things. I'm assuming `foo.js` isn't linked up to `StudentsController` and doesn't see `@students`. What's the right way to wire JavaScript this way so I can have access to javascript variables with my server-side objects?

Comment: Try to use the gon gem

Answer (score 2):

One problem here is simply that your file should be called `foo.js.erb` to compile ruby.

Also, I think you want to do this:

```
var class_a = <%= @students.select { |s| s.class_id == 'a' }.to_json %>
```

(Notice the double equal sign)

You might even be better to find the specific student in your controller and pass each through individually - this would be a better separation of concerns and would keep this logic out of your views.

Comment: Do I then have to add `foo.js` to my HTML?

Comment: You should checkout the docs on the Asset Pipeline to understand how it all works together: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html